# Object refer. not set to an instance of an object Unity.Netcode.NetworkMetrics.GetObjectIdentifier?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity based on a tutorial I saw on youtube. After finishing the game, I haven't touched the project for 1 week, when I open the project and try to play it, I get this error if I press "E" or "Esc" (E- Interact; Esc- Pause) in GameScene. I couldn't find a solution on the internet, can anyone help me?

Error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.Netcode.NetworkMetrics.GetObjectIdentifier (Unity.Netcode.NetworkObject networkObject) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.2.0/Runtime/Metrics/NetworkMetrics.cs:527)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkMetrics.TrackRpcSent (System.UInt64 receiverClientId, Unity.Netcode.NetworkObject networkObject, System.String rpcName, System.String networkBehaviourName, System.Int64 bytesCount) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.2.0/Runtime/Metrics/NetworkMetrics.cs:342)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkBehaviour.__endSendServerRpc (Unity.Netcode.FastBufferWriter& bufferWriter, System.UInt32 rpcMethodId, Unity.Netcode.ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams, Unity.Netcode.RpcDelivery rpcDelivery) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.2.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkBehaviour.cs:107)
KitchenGameManager.SetPlayerReadyServerRpc (Unity.Netcode.ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams) (at D:/DOMINO/Unity Projelerim/KitchenChaosMultiplayer/Assets/Scripts/KitchenGameManager.cs:103)
KitchenGameManager.GameInput_OnInteractAction (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) (at D:/DOMINO/Unity Projelerim/KitchenChaosMultiplayer/Assets/Scripts/KitchenGameManager.cs:97)
GameInput.Interact_performed (UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction+CallbackContext obj) (at D:/DOMINO/Unity Projelerim/KitchenChaosMultiplayer/Assets/Scripts/GameInput.cs:67)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities.DelegateHelpers.InvokeCallbacksSafe[TValue] (UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities.CallbackArray`1[System.Action`1[TValue]]& callbacks, TValue argument, System.String callbackName, System.Object context) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5.1/InputSystem/Utilities/DelegateHelpers.cs:46)
UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0(NativeInputUpdateType, NativeInputEventBuffer*)
UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate(NativeInputUpdateType, IntPtr)

NullReferenceException while executing 'performed' callbacks of 'Player/Interact[/Keyboard/e]'
UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.NativeInputRuntime/<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0 (UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateType,UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputEventBuffer*)
UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate (UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateType,intptr)

Codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 
public class KitchenGameManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
 
    public static KitchenGameManager Instance { get; private set; }
 
    public event EventHandler OnStateChanged;
    public event EventHandler OnLocalGamePaused;
    public event EventHandler OnLocalGameUnPaused;
    public event EventHandler OnMultiplayerGamePaused;
    public event EventHandler OnMultiplayerGameUnPaused;
    public event EventHandler OnLocalPlayerReadyChanged;
 
 
    private enum State {
        WaitingToStart,
        CountDownToStart,
        GamePlaying,
        GameOver,
    }
 
    [SerializeField] private Transform playerPrefab;
 
    private NetworkVariable<State> state = new NetworkVariable<State>(State.WaitingToStart);
    private bool isLocalPlayerReady;
    private NetworkVariable<float> countdownToStartTimer = new NetworkVariable<float>(3f);
    private NetworkVariable<float> gamePlayingTimer = new NetworkVariable<float>(0f);
    private float gamePlayingTimerMax = 1000f;
    private bool isLocalGamePaused = false;
    private NetworkVariable<bool> isGamePaused = new NetworkVariable<bool>(false);
    private Dictionary<ulong, bool> playerReadyDictionary;
    private Dictionary<ulong, bool> playerPausedDictionary;
    private bool autoTestGamePausedState;
 
    public static bool interactionsEnabled = false;
 
    private void Awake() {
        Instance = this;  
 
        playerReadyDictionary = new Dictionary<ulong, bool>();
        playerPausedDictionary = new Dictionary<ulong, bool>();
    }
 
    private void Start() {
        GameInput.Instance.OnPauseAction += GameInput_OnPauseAction;
        GameInput.Instance.OnInteractAction += GameInput_OnInteractAction;
    }
 
    public override void OnNetworkSpawn() {
        state.OnValueChanged += State_OnValueChanged;
        isGamePaused.OnValueChanged += IsGamePaused_OnValueChanged;
 
        if (IsServer) {
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += NetworkManager_OnClientDisconnectCallback;
            NetworkManager.Singleton.SceneManager.OnLoadEventCompleted += SceneManager_OnLoadEventCompleted;
        }
    }
 
    private void SceneManager_OnLoadEventCompleted(string sceneName, UnityEngine.SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode, List<ulong> clientsCompleted, List<ulong> clientsTimedOut) {
        foreach (ulong clientId in NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsIds) {
            Transform playerTransform = Instantiate(playerPrefab);
            playerTransform.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().SpawnAsPlayerObject(clientId, true);
        }
    }
 
    private void NetworkManager_OnClientDisconnectCallback(ulong clientId) {
        autoTestGamePausedState = true;
    }
 
    private void IsGamePaused_OnValueChanged(bool previousValue, bool newValue) {
        if (isGamePaused.Value) {
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
 
            OnMultiplayerGamePaused?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        } else {
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
 
            OnMultiplayerGameUnPaused?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
 
    private void State_OnValueChanged(State previousValue, State newValue) {
        OnStateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 
    private void GameInput_OnInteractAction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (state.Value == State.WaitingToStart) {
            isLocalPlayerReady = true;
            OnLocalPlayerReadyChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
 
            SetPlayerReadyServerRpc();
        }
    }
 
    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SetPlayerReadyServerRpc(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default) {
        playerReadyDictionary[serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId] = true;
 
        bool allClientsReady = true;
        foreach (ulong clientId in NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsIds) {
            if (!playerReadyDictionary.ContainsKey(clientId) || !playerReadyDictionary[clientId]) {
                // This player is NOT ready
                allClientsReady = false;
                break;
            }
        }
 
        if (allClientsReady) {
            state.Value = State.CountDownToStart;
        }
    }
 
    private void GameInput_OnPauseAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        TogglePauseGame();
    }
 
    private void Update() {
        if (!IsServer) {
            return;
        }
 
        switch (state.Value) {
            case State.WaitingToStart:
                break;
            case State.CountDownToStart:
                countdownToStartTimer.Value -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (countdownToStartTimer.Value < 0f) {
                    state.Value = State.GamePlaying;
                    gamePlayingTimer.Value = gamePlayingTimerMax;            
                }
                break;
            case State.GamePlaying:
                gamePlayingTimer.Value -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (gamePlayingTimer.Value < 0f) {
                    state.Value = State.GameOver;
                }
                break;
            case State.GameOver:
                break;      
        }
    }
 
    private void LateUpdate() {
        if (autoTestGamePausedState) {
            autoTestGamePausedState = false;
            TestGamePausedState();
        }
    }
 
    public bool IsGamePlaying() {
        return state.Value == State.GamePlaying;
    }
 
    public bool IsCountdownToStartActive() {
        return state.Value == State.CountDownToStart;
    }
 
    public float GetCountdownToStartTimer() {
        return countdownToStartTimer.Value;
    }
 
    public bool IsGameOver() {
        return state.Value == State.GameOver;
    }
 
    public bool IsWaitingToStart() {
        return state.Value == State.WaitingToStart;
    }
 
    public bool IsLocalPlayerReady() {
        return isLocalPlayerReady;
    }
 
    public float GetGamePlayingTimerNormalized() {
        return 1 - (gamePlayingTimer.Value / gamePlayingTimerMax);
    }
 
    public void TogglePauseGame() {
        isLocalGamePaused = !isLocalGamePaused;
        if (isLocalGamePaused) {
            PauseGameServerRpc();
 
            OnLocalGamePaused?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else {
            UnPauseGameServerRpc();
 
            OnLocalGameUnPaused?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
 
    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void PauseGameServerRpc(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default) {
        playerPausedDictionary[serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId] = true;
 
        TestGamePausedState();
    }
 
    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void UnPauseGameServerRpc(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default) {
        playerPausedDictionary[serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId] = false;
 
        TestGamePausedState();
    }
 
    private void TestGamePausedState() {
        foreach (ulong clientId in NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsIds) {
            if (playerPausedDictionary.ContainsKey(clientId) && playerPausedDictionary[clientId]) {
                // This player is paused
                isGamePaused.Value = true;
                return;
            }
        }
 
        // All players are unpaused
        isGamePaused.Value = false;
    }
 
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
 
public class GameInput : MonoBehaviour {
 
    private const string PLAYER_PREFS_BINDINGS = "InputBindings";
 
    public static GameInput Instance { get; private set; }
 
    public event EventHandler OnInteractAction;
    public event EventHandler OnInteractAlternateAction;
    public event EventHandler OnPauseAction;
    public event EventHandler OnBindingRebind;
 
    public enum Binding {
        Move_Up,
        Move_Down,
        Move_Left,
        Move_Right,
        Interact,
        InteractAlternate,
        Pause,
    }
 
    private PlayerInputActions playerInputActions;
 
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
 
        playerInputActions = new PlayerInputActions();
       
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(PLAYER_PREFS_BINDINGS)) {
            playerInputActions.LoadBindingOverridesFromJson(PlayerPrefs.GetString(PLAYER_PREFS_BINDINGS));
        }
        playerInputActions.Player.Enable();
       
        playerInputActions.Player.Interact.performed += Interact_performed;
        playerInputActions.Player.InteractAlternate.performed += InteractAlternate_performed;
        playerInputActions.Player.Pause.performed += Pause_performed;
 
    }
 
    private void OnDetsroy() {
        playerInputActions.Player.Interact.performed -= Interact_performed;
        playerInputActions.Player.InteractAlternate.performed -= InteractAlternate_performed;
        playerInputActions.Player.Pause.performed -= Pause_performed;
 
        playerInputActions.Dispose();
    }
 
    private void Pause_performed(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj) {
        OnPauseAction?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 
    private void InteractAlternate_performed(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        OnInteractAlternateAction?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 
    private void Interact_performed(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        OnInteractAction?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 
    public Vector2 GetMovementVectorNormalized()
    {
        Vector2 inputVector = playerInputActions.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        inputVector = inputVector.normalized;
        return inputVector;
    }
 
    public string GetBindingText(Binding binding) {
        switch (binding) {
            default:
            case Binding.Move_Up:
                return playerInputActions.Player.Move.bindings[1].ToDisplayString();
            case Binding.Move_Down:
                return playerInputActions.Player.Move.bindings[2].ToDisplayString();
            case Binding.Move_Left:
                return playerInputActions.Player.Move.bindings[3].ToDisplayString();
            case Binding.Move_Right:
                return playerInputActions.Player.Move.bindings[4].ToDisplayString();
            case Binding.Interact:
                return playerInputActions.Player.Interact.bindings[0].ToDisplayString();
            case Binding.InteractAlternate:
                return playerInputActions.Player.InteractAlternate.bindings[0].ToDisplayString();
            case Binding.Pause:
                return playerInputActions.Player.Pause.bindings[0].ToDisplayString();
        }
    }
 
    public void RebindBinding(Binding binding, Action OnActionRebound) {
        playerInputActions.Player.Disable();
 
        InputAction inputAction;
        int bindingIndex;
 
        switch (binding) {
            default:
            case Binding.Move_Up:
                inputAction = playerInputActions.Player.Move;
                bindingIndex = 1;
                break;
            case Binding.Move_Down:
                inputAction = playerInputActions.Player.Move;
                bindingIndex = 2;
                break;
            case Binding.Move_Left:
                inputAction =playerInputActions.Player.Move;
                bindingIndex = 3;
                break;
            case Binding.Move_Right:
                inputAction = playerInputActions.Player.Move;
                bindingIndex = 4;
                break;
            case Binding.Interact:
                inputAction = playerInputActions.Player.Interact;
                bindingIndex = 0;
                break;
            case Binding.InteractAlternate:
                inputAction = playerInputActions.Player.InteractAlternate;
                bindingIndex = 0;
                break;
            case Binding.Pause:
                inputAction = playerInputActions.Player.Pause;
                bindingIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
 
        inputAction.PerformInteractiveRebinding(bindingIndex)
            .OnComplete(callback => {
                callback.Dispose();
                playerInputActions.Player.Enable();
                OnActionRebound();
 
                PlayerPrefs.SetString(PLAYER_PREFS_BINDINGS, playerInputActions.SaveBindingOverridesAsJson());
                PlayerPrefs.Save();
 
                OnBindingRebind?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        })
        .Start();
}
}
```

I can't say much more than what I can say above because I didn't get this error after changing something. I can only say that it works fine in the build.

Comment: your `default`-switch-case should be the last one, not the first one. Just an asside, I doubt this causes your error.